# _Click() event not firing sub VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have added a rectangle shape to a spreadsheet.  I now wish to use a macro on event RectangleA_Click().  I know the shape's name is RectangleA as I have the below sub:

```
Sub f()
Dim Shape As Shape
For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print Shape.Name
Next
End Sub
```

I have written the code:

```
Private Sub RectangleA_Click()
    MsgBox "hello"
End Sub
```

In the relevant sheet object space in the editor.  On clicking the shape the subroutine is not called.

I am aware that I can assign this using right click> assign macro, but would prefer to avoid this as it seems like an unnecessary step.  I'm also aware that there are Active X controls which automatically assign the macro, again I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I think you can only add the Click event by assigning the macro with shapes (and form controls inserted on the sheet).  If you use ActiveX controls you can have the Click, Dbl_Click, MouseDown, etc events and assign them in the VBE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
Sub AssignMacroToShape()
   Set shpTemp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1680#, 594#, 120#, 74.25)
     shpTemp.OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!Macro Name"
End Sub
```

But it will be much easier just to right click > Assign Macro.

This above code is useful if you need to create the shape then assign a macro to it after creation.

You can look into the OnAction event to get the answer to specifics if this doesn't help.